# Hive query to find difference between two timestamp

Tags: sql, unix, hive

I have two timestamp request and response. I need to find out difference between two these two timestamp in millisecond as below.

```
Request: 2020-03-20 10:00:00:010
Response: 2020-03-20 10:00:00:020
Diff: 10 millisecond
```

I tried but could not get my required answer.
I tried as below but it is giving me 0 instead of 10.

```
select (unix_timestamp(2020-03-20 10:00:00:010) - unix_timestamp(2020-03-20 10:00:00:020))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because unix_timestamp trims out the millisecond portion.
You need some regex to parse it - something like:

```
select cast(regexp_replace('2020-03-20 10:00:00:020', 
                           '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{3})',
                           '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7') as timestamp);
```

OR

```
SELECT ROUND((CAST(CAST('2020-03-20 10:00:00.020' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) 
            - CAST(CAST('2020-03-20 10:00:00.010' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE)) * 1000)
as timediff
```

The millisecond portion should of the form yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS
So you may have to replace the ":" with "." for milliseconds.

Comment: How to use second query if millisecond with ":" eg: 2020-03-20 10:00:00:020

Comment: Regex replace the last ":" with "."

Answer (score 1):

Hive timestamp will be always something like:

```
2020-03-20 01:50:19.158
```

To get the difference between the two timestamps, you can try running below query:

```
select date_format("2020-03-20 10:00:00.020",'S') -date_format("2020-03-20 10:00:00.010",'S');
```

If the millisecond part is separated by ":" , then you can get the difference by running below query:

```
select cast(substr("2020-03-20 10:00:00:020",-3) as int) -  cast(substr("2020-03-20 10:00:00:010",-3) as int);
```